# what does "dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc -S failed" mean?

Tags: dpkg, packaging

I was trying to build a simple Debian package, 
I did these steps with user root:

---

First, I downloaded the upstream tarball, then:

```
 $ mv hithere-1.0.tar.gz hithere_1.0.orig.tar.gz
```

Then:

```
 $ tar xf hithere_1.0.orig.tar.gz
```

After that:

```
 $ cd hithere-1.0
 $ dch --create -v 1.0-1 --package hithere 
 $ cd debian/
 $ rm *.ex *.EX
```

Then I edited "control file" and "copyright file":

```
 $ nano control
 $ nano copyright


 $ cd ..
 $ debuild -S
```

After the last command, This error was generated:

```
root@mehrnaz-MS-A934:/home/fabdollahei/hithere-1.0# debuild -S dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc -S
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: using a gain-root-command while being root
dpkg-buildpackage: source package hithere
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 1.0-1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution unstable
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by root <f.abdollahei@itrc.ac.ir>
dpkg-source --before-build hithere-1.0
dpkg-source: error: syntax error in hithere-1.0/debian/control at line 15: block lacks the 'Package' field
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source --before-build hithere-1.0 gave error exit status 255
dpkg-source: error: syntax error in hithere-1.0/debian/control at line 15: block lacks the 'Package' field
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source --before-build hithere-1.0 gave error exit status 255
debuild: fatal error at line 1364:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc -S failed
```

How do I get rid of that fatal error?

Comment: Use `debuild -uc -us` unless you really want an only-source build (unlikely).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is just saying that `dpkg-buildpackage` command failed. If you read the messages you will notice where's the problem right away:

```
dpkg-source: error: syntax error in hithere-1.0/debian/control at line 15:
block lacks the 'Package' field
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source --before-build hithere-1.0 gave error exit status 255
```

If you fix that (and maybe other problems it has, that could show up later) it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -uc -us -S failed` means;

1. `dpkg-buildpackage` is the name of the command that was run. dpkg-buildpackage is a tool for building Debian packages or '.debs'.
2. `-rfakeroot` is the first argument to the command and tells dpkg-buildpackage to act as if dpkg-buildpackage had root privileges. From the man page; "When  dpkg-buildpackage  needs  to  execute  part  of the build process as root, it prefixes the command it executes with", in this case, fakeroot. (Don't use `su`).
3. The `-d` flag means "Do not check build dependencies and conflicts".
4. `-uc` and `-us` mean don't sign the changes file or the source code respectively.
5. `-S` means build a source package. Debian packages come in two types; binary and source. The binary is built from the source package.
6. "failed" means that the command failed, but I guess you knew this. :-)